# How to submit and edit data from database of paritcular id on same page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Good Evening, Everybody..

i am using php form to submit data of students in database using the below code...

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
$a1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a1']);
$a2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a2']);
$a3=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a3']);
$a=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a']);
$a4=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a4']);
$a5=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a5']);
$a6=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a6']);
$color=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['color']);
$date=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
$query1=mysql_query("insert into student_table values('','$a1','$a2','$a3','$a','$a4','$a5','$a6','$color','$date')");

if($query1)
{
echo "Open Updated Successfully";
}
}
?>

<div class="RECORD" align="center"><font color="red" size="4">! STUDENT RESULTS !</font><div class="HEADLINES">! Live Result !<br>
<font color="yellow"><?php

$query1 = "SELECT CONCAT(a1,a2,a3,' - ',a,' - ',a4,a5,a6) FROM student_table ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysql_query($query1);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $data[0];

?></font></div><hr>

<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
DATE:<input type="text" name="date" size="6" align="absmiddle" value="<?php
$current_dayname = date("l");

echo $date = date("d/m/y",strtotime('monday this week')).' <br>to<br> '.date("d/m/y",strtotime("sunday this week"));  
?>">
<br><br>Open: 
<input type="text" name="a1" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a1']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="a2" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a2']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="a3" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a3']; ?>"> - 
<input type="text" name="a" size="2" value="<?php echo $query2['a']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit1">
</form>

    <?php

$query1 = "SELECT id FROM student_table ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysql_query($query1);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);


    ?>
```

Now By using the above code it shows desired result....

but i want to add one more result along with previous result, due to this i have to required edit page of above result, the desired code of edit page is below...

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
$a1=$_POST['a1'];
$a2=$_POST['a2'];
$a3=$_POST['a3'];
$a=$_POST['a'];
$a4=$_POST['a4'];
$a5=$_POST['a5'];
$a6=$_POST['a6'];
$color=$_POST['color'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$query3=mysql_query("update student_table set a1='$a1', a2='$a2', a3='$a3', a='$a', a4='$a4', a5='$a5', a6='$a6', color='$color', date='$date' where id='$id'");
if($query3)
{
echo "</br> Close Updated Successfully";
}
}
$query1=mysql_query("select * from student_table where id='$id'");
$query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
?>

<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" name="a4" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a4']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="a5" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a5']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="a6" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a6']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="a" size="2" value="<?php echo $query2['a']; ?>"><select type="text"  name="color" value="<?php echo $query2['color']; ?>"> <option value="#000000">Black</option><option value="#FF0000">Red</option></select>
<input type="submit" name="submit2"><br>
<div style="background:black; color:black; font-size:1px">DATE:<input type="text" name="date" size="5" align="absmiddle" value="<?php
$current_dayname = date("l");

echo $date = date("d/m/y",strtotime('monday this week')).' <br>to<br> '.date("d/m/y",strtotime("sunday this week"));  
?>"><input type="text" name="a1" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a1']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="a2" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a2']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="a3" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a3']; ?>"></div>


</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Now my question is that....is it possible to perform both submitting of students numbers and having an option to add one more same result with editable function of previous result entry on the same page...

please refer below image...

[image]

can anybody help me in order to perform both functioning on same page with editable option

Comment: Need to narrow this down to far more specific issues. Concept in question is too broad and specific problem is not clear. This isn't a tutorial service